# AlertDialog Theme: How to change item text color?

Tags: android, themes, android-alertdialog

When I try to apply a standard theme to `AlertDialog`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyClass.this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT);

builder.setTitle("Change");

String[] info= this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.info);

ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);

arrayAdapter.addAll(info);

builder.setSingleChoiceItems(arrayAdapter, ....
```

Result:

[image]

The note is that I have no problem with `builder.setItems(...)` since its text color is `Black` while the theme applied with `builder.setSingleChoiceItems(...)` has a White text color.

Any fast fix? Or any way to create a customized theme based on `AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT` ?

My customized style doesn't work as expected:

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustomTheme" android:parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#7ABDFF</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>


    <!--THE FOLLOWING ITEMS HAVE NOT EFFECT ... !! -->

    <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">#A844BD</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">#7ABDFF</item>
</style>
```

**Update**

@lopez answer is a complete solution, but I find a single line fix for my problem, a custom theme to be applied to the activity in manifest:

```
<style name="MyTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that attribute is only available in APIs 11 and above

Answer (score 66):

If anyone happens to read this, and is using the Suport library Alert Dialogs and wants to change the text color of list items then drop the android: part, like so:

```
<item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/your_color</item>
```

Comment: And this for coloring the unselected radio buttons `<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/your_color</item>`

Comment: if anyone got stuck here like I did, try adding `android:` prefix to the item name .. suddenly started working

Comment: Hi there! Is there any possibility to make it worked for `parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog"`? In my case it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkDelphi I had the same problem. Did you find any solution for changing color

Comment: @Ravikiran Hi. Unfortunately, not yet. I am gonna try to use a custom layout instead.

Comment: Add <color name="color_on_surface">your_color</color> in colors.xml

Comment: NOTE: You must use "textColorAlertDialogListItem" rather than "android:textColorAlertDialogListItem" for API 21+.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I use the android `Dialog` but I use a custom layout for that match the design of my application.

Here is an example:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_delete_contact, null))
.setPositiveButton(context.getResources().getString(android.R.string.ok).toUpperCase(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // YOUR TREATMENT
    }
})
.setNegativeButton(context.getResources().getString(android.R.string.cancel).toUpperCase(), null)
.show();
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/GrayLight"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="DisableBaselineAlignment" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/remove_contact"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="DisableBaselineAlignment" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/ask_remove_contact"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Result in picture:

[image]

To avoid rewriting the code every time here is a utility class :

```
public class MyDialog {

public static Builder create(final Context context, final LayoutInflater layoutInflater, final String title, final String content) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.generic_dialog, null);
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitleDialog)).setText(title);
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewContentDialog)).setText(content);
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setView(view);
}

}
```

And an example of using :

```
AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = MyDialog.create(this, getLayoutInflater(), "Quitter ECOLEMS", "Voulez-vous vraiment quitter l'application?");
myDialog.setPositiveButton("Oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        // YOUR TREATMENT
    }
})
.setNegativeButton("Non", null)
.show();
```

I hope you have helped!

Answer (score 4):

What works for me

```
<style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text</item>
    <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/text</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me for every color on my dialog:

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">#00ffff</item>
    <!-- Used for the title and text -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#00ff00</item>
    <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">#ffff00</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ff00ff</item>
    <!-- Used for the background -->
    <item name="android:background">#3a3a3c</item>
</style>
```

[image: Every color of my alert dialog.]

Answer (score -4):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyClass.this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT);

builder.setTitle("Change");

String[] info= this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.info);

ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);

arrayAdapter.addAll(info);

builder.setSingleChoiceItems(arrayAdapter, ....**change this line to**

builder.setSingleChoiceItems(info,0,null);
```