# How to change the color of an dialog item from black to white?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-styles, android-dialog

I'm using the following theme for my dialog:

```
<style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

Everything works but the item text color. I need to be white, but for some reason, it remains back. How can I change that text to be white? Thanks

[image]

Edit:

Here is my AppTheme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609262/change-text-color-of-alert-dialog

Comment: or have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33437398/how-to-change-textcolor-in-alertdialog?

Comment: @JyotishBiswas Thank you but that answers doesn't help me solve the problem. Besides that I don't have any YES/NO buttons.

Comment: @RandomUser70-1 Thank you but that answers doesn't help me solve the problem. Besides that I don't have any YES/NO buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer [AlertDialog Theme: How to change item text color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230933/alertdialog-theme-how-to-change-item-text-color)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

or

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogStyle </item>
</style>
```

```
<style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    ...
    <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <!--
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    -->
</style>
```

Also you can change android:textColor, but it will change all the text color in Dialog Window

Answer (score 0):

Use your custom DialogBox Style while creating DialogBox.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AlertDialogStyle))
```

Add these lines into your app theme

```
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogStyle</item>
<item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/AlertDialogStyle</item>
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't make any change. The text is still black.

Comment: Share your app theme as well